# MySQL Trigger on failed update calls insert

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I would like to have a Trigger on a failed Update which will insert into the same table.

If possible, I would prefer avoiding any additional php and SELECT due to performance.

So I thought of something like this for the TRIGGER:

```
CREATE TRIGGER `onChunksUpdate` AFTER UPDATE ON  `chunks` 
FOR EACH ROW 

IF ROW_COUNT() = 0 
THEN INSERT INTO chunks( scopeX, scopeY, targets ) 
VALUES (NEW.scopeX, NEW.scopeY, NEW.targets);
END IF ;
```

And the executed Update statement(php):

```
UPDATE chunks SET targets = CONCAT(targets, ',{$id}') WHERE scopeX={$chunkX} AND scopeY={$chunkY}
```

Furthermore I am not sure, wether a failed update call would still execute a TRIGGER of the time AFTER.

Thanks for any help, I googled very much to find any help but I found nothing.

Comment: I hope you're [escaping those values](http://bobby-tables.com/php) because it doesn't look like you are.

Comment: for sure I do. I just like to keep my SQL Strings clean

Comment: You should not use string concatenation to compose queries when placeholders are a much more reliable method of introducing data into your query. PDO even has named placeholders to help avoid binding data to the wrong column by accident.